# dropped from memory error with graphX query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Using graphX API of apache-spark, I wrote the following code which generates the Graph successfully. But, when I try to query this graph, some memory related error occurs

```
val RDDorg = sc.textFile("output.txt")
val RDDstart = RDDorg.map(line => line.split("#"))
val rddPersons = RDDstart.map(line => line(0)).union(RDDstart.map(line=>line(2))).distinct().zipWithIndex()
val verticesRDD = rddPersons.map(_.swap)
val rddSender = rddPersons.join(RDDstart.map(line => (line(0),line(1)))).values.map(_.swap).distinct()
val rddReceiver = rddPersons.join(RDDstart.map(line => (line(2),line(1)))).values.map(_.swap).distinct()
val msgid= RDDstart.map(line => line(1)).distinct().zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)
val mrg = verticesRDD.union(msgid).zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)
val distVertices = (mrg.map(line => (line._1,line._2._2))).map(_.swap)
val rddEdge = rddSender.join(rddReceiver).map(line => (line._2._1,line._2._2,line._1))
val mrgrdd = distVertices.join(rddEdge.map(line=> (line._3,line._2)))
val nxt_2 = (mrgrdd.map(line => (line._1,line._2._2,line._2._1)))
val test = nxt_2.map(line=> (line._1,line._3))
val test2 = test.join(rddEdge.map(line => (line._3,line._2)))
val test3 = test.join(rddEdge.map(line => (line._3,line._1)))
val final_coll = test3.join(test2)
val senderEdge = final_coll.map(line => (line._2._1._2, line._2._1._1,line._1))
val RcvrEdge = final_coll.map(line => (line._2._2._1, line._2._2._2,line._1))
val FinalEdge = senderEdge.union(RcvrEdge)
val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] = FinalEdge.map { line =>
Edge(line._1,line._2,line._3 ) }.distinct()

 /////////////////////////////////////
class rootclass{}
case class UserNode(sName:String, sno:String, sDept:String) extends rootclass with Serializable
case class MessageNode(mID:String, received:String, toAddr:String, ccAddr:String, dkim:String, recv_spf:String, in_reply:String,
                              references:String, return_path:String, from:String, subject:String, content_type:String, dateTime:String,
                              del_dateTime:String, envelopTo:String, deliveredTo:String, importance:String, userAgent:String,
                              Xpriority:Int) extends rootclass with Serializable
 val users: RDD[rootclass] = verticesRDD.map { line =>val cols = line._2.split(",")
        (new UserNode(cols(0), cols(1), cols(2)))
      }
val Message: RDD[rootclass] = msgid.map { line => val cols = line._2.split("%")
        (new MessageNode(cols(0), cols(1), cols(2), cols(3), cols(4), cols(5),cols(6),cols(7), cols(8), cols(9), cols(10), cols(11), cols(12), cols(13), cols(14), cols(15),cols(16), cols(17),cols(18).toInt))
 }

val nodes = (users union Message).zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)

val graph = Graph.apply(nodes, edges)
val num= graph.numVertices
```

I get an error if I try to use  *graph.numvertices*

```
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 90, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 3940 bytes)
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO Executor: Running task 6.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 90)
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 89) in 45114 ms on localhost (5/12)
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 4 non-empty blocks out of 4 blocks
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 6 non-empty blocks out of 6 blocks
15/10/09 12:10:55 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
15/10/09 12:11:06 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 4 non-empty blocks out of 4 blocks
15/10/09 12:11:06 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
15/10/09 12:16:59 INFO Executor: Finished task 6.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 90). 1011 bytes result sent to driver
15/10/09 12:16:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 88)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$join$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$join$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:485)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer$$anon$1.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:113)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.map(CompactBuffer.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$join$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$join$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:485)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer$$anon$1.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:113)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.flatMap(CompactBuffer.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$join$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$join$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.FlatMappedValuesRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(FlatMappedValuesRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.FlatMappedValuesRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(FlatMappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
```

Please suggest me where I made a mistake.

Thanks

Comment: already added these lines to spark config file to increase alloted execution memory: 1) # spark.driver.memory  4g,
2)# spark.executor.memory  2g

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded (edited)

Comment: Thats better. It could be useful if you isolate the place where it happens. Some additional information about your data and cluster wouldn't hurt to. Otherwise the best advice anyone can give you is probably to increase memory even more :)